# Hibernate Errors After Migrating From Grails 2 to Grails 3

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-2.0

We recently updated our application from Grails 2 to Grails 3, folowing the recommended guidelines at https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html#upgradingApps

Now, when we run our application, we get Hibernate warnings for pretty much our entire database, but the application will start and the connection to the database seems to be operating normally. I'm concerned about the warnings and I'm including the log of the `:bootRun` command below (with 4500 lines of similar errors redacted). I'm also including our `build.gradle` file.

I think I may be having trouble finding the right combination of dependencies, or I missed something during our migration. Any suggestions?

#### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "com.mycompany.myproject"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

war {
    archiveName "${war.baseName}.war"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "http://maven.int.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/" }
}

//ext {
//    set "tomcat.version", "8.5.5"
//}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.11"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"

    // Comment out or not?
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.3.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.3.Final"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.1"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    compile 'org.ehcache:ehcache:3.3.1'

    runtime "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3.0"

    // Dependencies recommended by the Spring Security UI Plugin
    // https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/v3/index.html
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-executor:0.4'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:jasypt-encryption:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:http-builder-helper:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6'

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

#### application.groovy

```
hibernate {
    // for debugging purposes only
    //format_sql = true
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

dataSources {
    dataSource {
        // logSql for debugging purposes only
        logSql = true
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        username = "db_user"
        password = "db_user"

        // http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    }
}

// environment specific database settings
environments {
    local {
        dataSources {
            dataSource {
                driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
                dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
                username = "sa"
                password = ""
            }
        }

        grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
        grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'
    }
    development {
        dataSources {
            dataSource {
                dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dev.db.myproject.int.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myproject_dev.int.mycompany.com)))"
            }
        }

        grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
        grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'
    }
}
```

#### :bootRun Log

```
4:25:58 PM: Executing external task 'bootRun -Dgrails.env=dev -Dconsole.log=true -Ddebug=true'...
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildProperties
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun
16:26:15,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c86a017 - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
16:26:15,853 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c86a017 - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:26:15,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c86a017 - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
16:26:16,043 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c86a017 - Setting level of logger [ROOT] to INFO
16:26:16,055 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@5c86a017 - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
16:26:17,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@89c10b7 - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
16:26:17,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@89c10b7 - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:26:17,776 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@89c10b7 - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
16:26:17,777 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@89c10b7 - Setting level of logger [ROOT] to INFO
16:26:17,777 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@3d08f3f5 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
16:26:17,779 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate@89c10b7 - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
16:26:17.882 [main] INFO  com.mycompany.myproject.Application - Starting Application on myserver with PID 18912 (C:\@Projects\myproject\myproject-ui\build\classes\main started by mymachine in C:\@Projects\myproject\myproject-ui)
16:26:17.889 [main] INFO  com.mycompany.myproject.Application - The following profiles are active: development
16:26:17.938 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d8bbcdc: startup date [Wed Jun 07 16:26:17 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
16:26:18.357 [background-preinit] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.5.Final
16:26:22.329 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Attempting to load [0] user defined plugins
16:26:22.331 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [dataBinding] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.331 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [restResponder] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [jasyptEncryption] with version [2.0.1] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [httpBuilderHelper] with version [1.0.2] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [core] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [i18n] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [mail] with version [2.0.0.RC6] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [eventBus] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.332 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [fields] with version [2.1.5] loaded successfully
16:26:22.340 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [urlMappings] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.341 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [dataSource] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.341 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [controllers] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.341 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [domainClass] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.342 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [groovyPages] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.342 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [mimeTypes] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.342 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [interceptors] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.342 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [codecs] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [converters] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [assetPipeline] with version [2.14.1] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [scaffolding] with version [3.3.3] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [hibernate] with version [6.0.10] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [controllersAsync] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [services] with version [3.2.9] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [executor] with version [0.4] loaded successfully
16:26:22.343 [main] INFO  g.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager - Grails plug-in [cache] with version [3.0.3] loaded successfully
16:26:24.423 [main] INFO  o.g.p.d.DataSourceGrailsPlugin - [RuntimeConfiguration] Configuring data source for environment: DEVELOPMENT
16:26:24.429 [main] INFO  o.g.p.d.DataSourceGrailsPlugin - [RuntimeConfiguration] Configuring data source 'externalDatasourceView' for environment: DEVELOPMENT
16:26:25.315 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionalEventListenerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalEventListenerFactory]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.316 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.316 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.317 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'multipartResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=multipartResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.317 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.grails.spring.aop.autoproxy.GroovyAwareAspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.318 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'characterEncodingFilter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=characterEncodingFilter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.318 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.grails.spring.context.support.GrailsPlaceholderConfigurer]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.319 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'multipartConfigElement' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=multipartConfigElement; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.320 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dispatcherServlet' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dispatcherServlet; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.320 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dispatcherServletRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.370 [main] INFO  g.p.cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor - postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry start
16:26:25.375 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager_externalDatasourceView' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.grails.datastore.gorm.bootstrap.support.InstanceFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
16:26:25.872 [main] INFO  g.p.cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor - postProcessBeanFactory
16:26:27.789 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
16:26:27.800 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service Tomcat
16:26:27.801 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
16:26:27.969 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
16:26:27.969 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10033 ms
16:26:37.175 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.3.Final}
16:26:37.178 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16:26:37.179 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
16:26:37.686 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
16:26:37.793 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
16:26:39.100 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  n.s.e.config.ConfigurationFactory - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Users/mymachine/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.3/cf74f9a4a049f181833b147a1d9aa62159c9d01d/ehcache-2.10.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
16:26:39.414 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.h.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache - HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
16:26:39.420 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
16:26:39.909 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.h.c.internal.StandardQueryCache - HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
16:26:39.909 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
16:26:40.202 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.mycompany.myproject.profile.Profile]; using defaults.
16:26:41.616 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.mycompany.myproject.security.Role]; using defaults.
16:26:42.906 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.mycompany.myproject.reference.NotKeyCitableReference]; using defaults.
Hibernate: alter table alert add constraint FK6pr6rbxsolgfa4l9mo8ngnvwn foreign key (alert_message_id) references alert_message
16:27:06.876 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    [[90+ LINES OF STACK TRACE REDACTED]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1909)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1871)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 97 common frames omitted


[[4500 LINES OF SIMILAR WARNINGS/ERRORS REDACTED]]


16:27:25.719 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
16:27:25.761 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
16:27:35.689 [main] INFO  g.a.i.c.mycompany.myproject.BootStrap - ========== BootStrap.init() Done. ==========
16:27:35.941 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16:27:35.994 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16:27:36.018 [main] INFO  o.a.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16:27:36.525 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
16:27:36.525 [main] INFO  o.g.w.s.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'grailsDispatcherServlet': initialization started
16:27:36.649 [main] INFO  o.g.w.s.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'grailsDispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 124 ms
16:27:36.649 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
16:27:36.663 [main] INFO  com.mycompany.myproject.Application - Started Application in 80.397 seconds (JVM running for 82.806)
16:27:36.663 [main] INFO  grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application starting in environment: development
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
16:27:43.264 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/js/dropdowntabs.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
16:27:44.332 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: Something is trying to run DDL statements on your database & you're hitting `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, is your datasource setup correctly or are you using the database migration plugin

Comment: Yes. Everything was setup and working correctly under Grails 2. Under Grails 3, we get these warnings/errors, but the database access once the application starts is correct. I can query tables and display the results as expected, so I think that implies that the datasource is configured properly. If there is a specific setting or configuration item I can check, I'd be happy to share that information.

Comment: Have you switched to application.yml or are you still using application.groovy? Either way what is dbCreate set to for the development datasource? The issue is this `Hibernate: alter table alert add constraint FK6pr6rbxsolgfa4l9mo8ngnvwn foreign key (alert_message_id) references alert_message`

Comment: I had tried application.yml briefly, but there are some configuration items that were set at runtime from environment specific database values, so we were keeping things in application.groovy. 

dbCreate is currently set to "update". 

An error is reported for the foreign key between alert and alert_message, but this field already exists and works fine once the application starts. I just don't understand why (hibernate?) this generates the error.

Comment: Maybe try clearing dbCreate & start to see if messages go away, if so there may be an issue between Grails view of your domain and the DB

Comment: @GeoGriffin Iam facing the same issue. Was there any fix u found..? Kindly share the fix